# Sublime Text 3 Stop Auto-Complete From Committing on 'Space'

Tags: python, autocomplete, settings, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 3, is there any way to stop the Auto-Complete from committing when pressing <kbd>space</kbd>? I see the `"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false` option in the settings, but nothing to stop pressing the <kbd>space</kbd> key from committing the selected entry.

Perhaps I can make use of some combination of the `"auto_complete_selector"` or `"auto_complete_triggers"` settings? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

To recreate, open a new buffer and verify that the syntax is set to *Plain Text*. Write

```
Blah
Test
Stuff
More Text
```

Now press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (or whatever you have the hotkey set to) to open the Completions List. Use the arrow keys to navigate to one of the choices and press <kbd>space</kbd>. This will automatically select the highlighted choice as if you had pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> (or <kbd>tab</kbd> if you have `"auto_complete_commit_on_tab"` set to `true`).

I want to stop Sublime Text from assuming that <kbd>space</kbd> means I want to select the highlighted completion.

Comment: At default Sublime Text does not trigger any auto complete on space. Do you use any packages in Sublime for auto complete?

Comment: I just downloaded the _Windows 64-bit Portable version_ without the package manager or any packages (other than the default ones) installed, and I am having the same issue.

Comment: Ah now your question is much clearer, thanks for your update. But I guess this behavior is not configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was asking this question because I was developing an auto-complete package ([Gherkin Auto-Complete Plus](https://github.com/austincrft/sublime-gherkin-auto-complete-plus)) for [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)'s [Gherkin](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#gherkin) language. Because the language uses human readable text, the commit on spaces made it practically useless.

Because I wanted to display the auto-complete results while typing (like you'd see in an IDE), I manage the displaying of said results in my package. The solution was hacky, but it works. I got the idea from the [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/) package.

The implementation can be seen in [gherkin_event_listener.py](https://github.com/austincrft/sublime-gherkin-auto-complete-plus/blob/master/gherkin_event_listener.py)

First, I defined a `_show_auto_complete` method on my `GherkinEventListener` class.

```
def _show_auto_complete(self, view):
    def _show_auto_complete():
        view.run_command('auto_complete', {
            'disable_auto_insert': True,
            'api_completions_only': True,
            'next_completion_if_showing': False,
            'auto_complete_commit_on_tab': True,
        })
    # Have to set a timeout for some reason
    sublime.set_timeout(_show_auto_complete, 0)
```

Note that a timeout must be set, even if it's `0`.

Then in the `on_modified` method of the `GherkinEventListener`, I did this:

```
view.settings().set('auto_complete', False)
pos = view_sel[0].end()
next_char = view.substr(sublime.Region(pos - 1, pos))

if next_char in (' ', '\n'):
    view.run_command('hide_auto_complete')
    return

view.run_command('hide_auto_complete')
self._show_auto_complete(view)
self._fill_completions(view, pos)
```

Note that you must fill the completions *after* calling `_show_auto_complete`, otherwise it will be set to `false` when filling and they won't display.